# How do I fix a "Wrong Type Argument: listp," error when trying to access remote file using tramp?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp, emacs24, tramp

I am unable to access remote files in my usual way:

C-x C-f
`[server]:[path][file]`

and am thrown this error:
`Wrong Type Argument: listp, [[server]:[path][file]`

I'm not even sure how to debug this further.

any help is appreciated.

edit:

output when trying to debug:

```
Debugger entered: nil
(progn (debug) (ido-mode t) (progn (ad-add-advice (quote completing-read) (quote (foo nil
 t  (advice lambda nil (if (boundp ...) ad-do-it (setq ad-return-value ...))))) (quote 
around) (quote nil)) (ad-activate (quote completing-read) nil) (quote completing-read)) (define-key global-map [(meta 120)] (function (lambda nil (interactive) (call-interactively
(intern (ido-completing-read "M-x " (all-completions "" obarray ...))))))))
(if (fboundp (quote ido-mode)) (progn (debug) (ido-mode t) (progn (ad-add-advice (quote
completing-read) (quote (foo nil t (advice lambda nil (if ... ad-do-it ...)))) (quote
around) (quote nil)) (ad-activate (quote completing-read) nil) (quote completing-read)) 
(define-key global-map [(meta 120)] (function (lambda nil (interactive) (call-
interactively (intern (ido-completing-read "M-x " ...))))))))
eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 16103
call-interactively(eval-buffer)
(lambda nil (interactive) (call-interactively (intern (ido-completing-read "M-x " (all-
completions "" obarray (quote commandp))))))()
call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (call-interactively (intern (ido-completing- 
read "M-x " (all-completions "" obarray (quote commandp)))))) nil nil)

recursive-edit()
debug(debug)
implement-debug-on-entry()
*  ido-find-file()
call-interactively(ido-find-file nil nil)
```

And this from my init.el:

```
(require 'ido)
(if (fboundp 'ido-mode)
(progn
  (debug)
  (ido-mode t)
  (defadvice completing-read
    (around foo activate)
    (if (boundp 'ido-cur-list)
        ad-do-it
      (setq ad-return-value
            (ido-completing-read
             prompt
             (all-completions "" collection predicate)
             nil require-match initial-input hist def))))
  (define-key global-map [(meta ?x)]
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively
       (intern
        (ido-completing-read "M-x " (all-completions "" obarray 'commandp))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what command `C-x C-f` is bound to (use `C-h k`).  Is it the standard binding `find-file`?  (It doesn't sound like it.)

If not, check its `interactive` spec.  The command is expecting to receive a list as argument, and it is instead receiving (what looks like) a string.

This is the `interactive` spec of `find-file`:

```
(interactive
 (find-file-read-args "Find file: " (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
```

If the `interactive` spec of your `C-x C-f` command, like this one, has a non-string as its argument, then you can either `M-x debug-on-entry THE-FUNCTION`, where `THE-FUNCTION` is the function called for the argument (`find-file-read-args`, in the case of `find-file`), or wrap that argument so that the debugger is invoked:

```
(progn (debug) (WHATEVER-WAS-THERE-BEFORE))
```

Either way, the debugger will open for the interactive part of reading the file name, and you can walk through the debugger to see what goes wrong.

But probably you can figure out the problem just by inspecting the code -- the `interactive` spec.  The argument to your command (whatever it is) is expected to be a list, but it is a string.

I would start by seeing what happens with a local file name.  Do you get an error for that too?

Another thing I notice is that the error reports an extra `[`, in front of what you say you typed as input.  That should provide a clue too.  What you think it is reading is not what it has read.

Comment: oops sorry i hit enter after copying and pasting there then ran out of time in the edit...
Let me try again...
Hi Drew and thank you for your very quick and detailed response.

C-x C-f runs the command ido-find-file as I have ido enabled.

Where would I find the <code>interactive</code> spec do you think?, its built into emacs but i'm not really sure where to look.

Comment: `ido-find-file` is in file `ido.el`. Its `interactive` spec is just `(interactive)`: it takes no arguments.  A cursory look at your debug output shows that something you are using has advised `completing-read` (and AFAICT, Ido does not do that). I suggest you start there: look for a `defadvice` of `completing-read` in your code or code that you load.  Try to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`, i.e., no init file -- add just what you need from your init file to repro the problem.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks again for taking the time to respond.

I don't seem to have ido.el as its built-in to my version of emacs.

My init.el contains that code you speak of, and always has, so I'm unsure why I'm only now having this issue.

When I remove everything except the line that (require 'ido) I lose tramp functionality.

I wonder if this may be a conflict between ido and yasnippet?

Comment: Hard to believe you have Emacs without the Lisp source code.  It is supposed to be delivered with the product (this is GNU, after all). Anyway, if you do not, it's hard to help. If you suspect yasnippet, try  not using it, to see if that helps.  Try bisecting your init file recursively, to narrow it down to the code that causes the problem.